# Run Python 3.6 in Terminal on Mac?

Tags: python, terminal, version-control

I am using a Python on a Mac and I know that Python 2 comes preinstalled on the system (and in fact usable through Terminal). Is there a way to make it so Terminal can run Python 3? Can/should you set this as a default? I know changing the default settings for Python version usage could break your system so should I just install Python 3 and then use it through its launch icon instead?

Comment: You shouldn't change the system Python because that can break things that expect it to be Python 2. But you can install Python 3 in addition to the system Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use python 3 in terminal after you have python 3 installed. Every time you run a command type `python3` instead of `python` if you are using pip to install modules you can do this:
But you must have pip installed for python 3

```
$ python3 -m pip install something
```

Comment: How do I make sure that I have pip installed for Python 3?

Comment: When you installed python 3 through the installer, did you check the include pip button?

Comment: You actually don't need to check, just run this code and if it spun ModuleNotFoundError then you don't have pip installed @Ethan

Comment: `python3 -m pip install something` in terminal. Replace something with the URL or if it's in pypi, the module's name

Comment: Or just do `python3 -m pip -V` and it will tell you which version of pip is installed and associated with that python3.

Comment: How do I run Python 3.6 specifically? Thanks.

Comment: @gnawy replace `python3` with `python3.6`

Answer (score 1):

Use can use python version management tool 
https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv

Answer (score 1):

Package manager:

```
pip3 install something
```

Interpreter:

```
python3
```

Answer (score 0):

Best option is to install Python through Anaconda. This allows easy management and much more. You can have virtual environments having different Python versions as well as different modules installed.

Comment: Once installing Anaconda (https://www.continuum.io/downloads) you can set environments having different versions of Python. There are a lot of tutorials out there.

Answer (score 0):

as usual in Mac python 2.7 is already installed, however if you installed python 3+ 
then you can just type in terminal: `python3` 
so that you can use the newer version that you installed.
if you want to use python 2.7 then just type: `python`